# How do you stop a Visual Studio generated web service proxy class from encoding?

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, wsdl, proxy-classes

I'm using a Visual Studio generated proxy class to access a web service (added the web service as a web reference to my project).  The problem is that the function the web service exposes expects a CDATA element, i.e.:

```
<Function><![CDATA[<Blah></Blah>]]></Function>
```

Unfortunately, when I pass in "" into the proxy class, it calls the web service with this:

```
<Function>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;Blah&gt;&lt;/Blah&gt;]]&gt;</Function>
```

This appears to be causing problems with the web service.  Is there any way to fix this while still using the proxy class generated by Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a code sample of how you're calling the webservice? If it's a web service with a published WSDL I don't know why you'd even have to address this level of implementation detail, so I have a suspicion that you're calling it wrong somehow.

Comment: Yes, this is generated from a published WSDL.  The WSDL says that the function being called simply takes in a string, and that's exactly what I'm passing it.  Unfortunately, when the web service proxy class generates the XML, it encodes the string I passed in.